# GQL only for Python projects and not for java?

Tags: java, python, database, google-app-engine, gql

In Google App Engine, GQL(an SQL-like query mechanism foe datastore) is available only for Python Projects and not for java projects. Why is it so?

Also it there anyway to overcome this and **use GQL in java projects also**?

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you want but I personally think GQL was a mistake. I have been developing with appengine (python) since it came out and have never found a use for  it in any project.  Too many people fall into the trap of thinking GQL is SQL and therefore  approach the appengine datastore with many preconcieved ideas.

Comment: ya.. I agree GQL has many contraints.. but that would be enough for some minor applications though.. but why for python why not for java?

Comment: Check this out: [gql4j](http://code.google.com/p/gql4j/) and [ExtendedGQLParser](http://code.google.com/p/audao/wiki/ExtendedGQLParser)

Comment: Remmeber you can not update with GQL, so you always have to abandon it at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GQL isn't in the Java implementation and as a replacement you would use the `Query` object to build datastore queries.

If you're looking for a GQL implementation for Java, gql4j works well enough.  I tested it out on a small data set to make sure it works but I haven't used it in a project otherwise.

http://code.google.com/p/gql4j/

Comment: I did not but it looked like a fairly stable project when I suggested it.